# Why bloom filters use the same array for all k hashing algorithms

Tags: algorithm, bloom-filter

I understand that in order to reduce the chance of a single hash colision to result a false positive bloom filters use multiple (k) hashes.

Wouldn't it be more beneficial to use k arrays, one for each hashing algorithm so that if by coinsidence many input keys are mapped by algorithm A to the same value and stored at the same array cell, and then another key is mapped by alorithm B to the same value - this is a valuable information that should be marked separately.
I think that k arrays of size m/k should give a better result than a single array of size m.
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to your intuition (and mine!), your proposed data structure will actually have a slightly *worse* false positive rate on lookups than a Bloom filter (assuming perfect hash functions), because you've eliminated the possibility of self-collision - that is, you've made it so that two hash functions run on the *same* element never return the same array index. That may sound like a good thing, but actually, it's bad, because it means that on average more bits will be set in the data structure you propose (henceforth, the "Akiva filter") than would be set in a Bloom filter of the same size, number of hash functions, and number of elements.

#### A simple example

To see starkly how eliminating self-collision *can* be bad, let's start by considering the extreme (and unrealistic) case where:

- *k*=2 (we have only two hash functions, *h₁* and *h₂*),
- *m*=4 (our filter is only 4 bits large), and
- we've added only one element, *x*, to our filter.

Suppose we then want to check whether some other value, *y*, is a member of the filter or not.

If our filter is a Bloom filter, there's a 25% chance that we got a lucky hash collision when we added *x* - i.e. that *h₁*(*x*) = *h₂*(*x*) and so the filter has only 1 bit set. *If* that's the case, then our chance of a false positive when we look up *y* is low - just 0.25 * 0.25 = 0.0625. On the other hand, if we got unlucky and *h₁*(*x*) ≠ *h₂*(*x*) (i.e. two bits in our Bloom filter are set), then our chance of a false positive when we look up *y* is 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.25. So our overall chance of a false positive is 0.25 * 0.0625 + 0.75 * 0.25 = 0.203125.

On the other hand, if our filter is an Akiva filter, split into two arrays of size *m*/*k*=2, then there is a 100% chance that after adding element *x* there are two bits set - one in the first sub-array and one in the second. So our chance of a false positive when we look up *y* is exactly 25%.

#### A general proof

Can we demonstrate that it is true *in general* that an Akiva filter has a worse false positive rate than a Bloom filter, regardless of the values of *m* (the number of bits in the data structure), *k* (the number of hash functions), and *n* (the number of elements that have been added to the filter)? Yes; to do so, let's first determine the probability of a false positive as an expression of *m*, *k*, and *n* for each data structure.

Let us start with the Akiva filter. We look up *k* distinct sub-array indexes of the element we are looking up, and each of them has a (completely independent) 1 - (1 - *k*/*m*)*ⁿ* chance of already being set, so our overall chance of a false positive is (1 - (1 - *k*/*m*)*ⁿ*)*ᵏ*.

Next, we consider the Bloom filter. Here we can defer to some [published scholarship](https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=903775):

> In the analysis of Bloom filter false positive rate it is typically assumed that the hash functions are perfect whereby they produce an independent and random index value for each object and thus the false positive rate is only a function of *m*, *n*, and *k*. The “classic” analysis of Bloom filter false positive rate is as follows. ... The probability that an arbitrary bit is not set after *k* bit insertions from the mapping of one object is  (1−1/*m*)*ᵏ*. For *n* objects mapped-in, the probability that an arbitrary bit is not set is (1 − 1/*m*)*ᵏⁿ* and therefore the probability that an arbitrary bit is set is *p<sub>set</sub>* = 1 - (1 − 1/*m*)*ᵏⁿ*. Thus, for *k* hashes for a test object not mapped in the Bloom filter, the probability of false positive is (we call this the “classic formula”),
>
> *p<sub>false</sub>* = *p<sub>set</sub>ᵏ* = (1 - (1 − 1/*m*)*ᵏⁿ*)*ᵏ*

So we have a false positive probability of (1 - (1 - *k*/*m*)*ⁿ*)*ᵏ* for the Akiva filter and (1 - (1 − 1/*m*)*ᵏⁿ*)*ᵏ* for the Bloom filter; but when is the former larger? The answer is that the Akiva filter's false positive rate is strictly larger (worse) for *k* ≥ 2, regardless of the values of *m* or *n*. To prove this, we first observe that the inequality we wish to prove, (1 - (1 - *k*/*m*)*ⁿ*)*ᵏ* > (1 - (1 − 1/*m*)*ᵏⁿ*)*ᵏ*, is equivalent to a much simpler inequality, by performing the following transformations:

- **(1 - (1 - *k*/*m*)*ⁿ*)*ᵏ* > (1 - (1 − 1/*m*)*ᵏⁿ*)*ᵏ***, iff
- **(1 - (1 - *k*/*m*)*ⁿ*) > (1 - (1 − 1/*m*)*ᵏⁿ*)** (by taking *k*th roots), iff
- **(1 - *k*/*m*)*ⁿ* < (1 − 1/*m*)*ᵏⁿ*** (by subtracting 1 from each side, then flipping the sign of both sides), iff
- **1 - *k*/*m* < (1 − 1/*m*)*ᵏ*** (by taking *n*th roots)

Finally we can easily prove that 1 - *k*/*m* < (1 − 1/*m*)*ᵏ* for all k≥2 by first observing that this is true for k=2:

1 - 2/*m* < 1 - 2/*m* + 1/*m*² = (1 − 1/*m*)*ᵏ*

... and then proceeding by induction. Suppose that (1 - (*k*-1)/*m*) < (1 − 1/*m*)<sup>*k*-1</sup>. Then we can express (1 − 1/*m*)<sup>*k*-1</sup> as (1 - (*k*-1)/*m*) + *ε*, for some *ε*>0. Then

(1 − 1/*m*)*ᵏ*
= (1 - 1/*m*)(1 - (*k*-1)/*m* + *ε*)
= 1 - (*k*-1)/*m* + *ε* - 1/*m* + (*k*-1)/*m*² - *ε*/*m*
= 1 - *k*/m + (1 - 1/*m*)*ε* + (*k*-1)/*m*²
> 1 - *k*/m

QED.

#### In conclusion

Burton Howard Bloom seems to have known what he was doing; the Bloom filter has a lower false positive rate than the alternative structure you contemplate with *k* distinct arrays, and is therefore superior.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `k << m`, it doesn't matter.

Whether we use one array of size `m` or `k` arrays of size `m/k`, a single bit for a thing stored in the filter will collide an average of `k/m` times with another thing stored in the same filter.  Since these individual pairwise collisions are essentially independent, the number of times each bit will collide with other objects follows the same Poisson distribution, and therefore the odds of a collision are the same and therefore the odds that every bit collides are the same and therefore the odds of a false positive is the same.

Therefore it is all about implementation simplicity.

Comment: @MooingDuck The memory usage of an array of size `m` is the same as of `k` arrays of size `m/k`. :-)

Comment: However a surprising fact is that if `H` and `K` are two independent good hash functions with `K` never producing `0` then you can make your `k` functions be `H(x)`, `H(x) + K(x)`, ..., `H(x) + (k-1)K(x)` (all operations mod `m`) and the Bloom filter is likely to work well.  This can be a significant performance enhancement because computing good hash functions is a lot more expensive than arithmetic.

Comment: But it does matter if the algorithms are not evenly distributed. In that case a value with lots of collisions for algorithm A is different than such a colision for algorithm B

Comment: @akiva If you have a hash based data structure and have a hash that doesn't work well, the hash structure doesn't work well.  This is expected.

Comment: but the entire idea of multiple hashes is for non-working-well hash algorithms. Otherwise one suffices

Comment: @akiva Do you know what a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter is?  That is the topic of discussion and one hash function **will not** suffice for reasons that have nothing to do with hash functions not working properly.  Another example of a hash based data structure that by design requires multiple hash functions is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing.

Comment: @akiva The reason for using multiple hashes is not that the hash algorithms used don't work well; it's that even if you have a perfect hashing algorithm, you have a chance of getting collisions by random chance, and this chance is high when the total number of distinct possible hashes is only modestly large relative to the number of elements you're hashing.

Comment: akiva's proposed filter actually has a slightly *worse* false positive probability, not an equal one as this answer claims. So where is the mistake? I think it's this claim: *"a single bit for a thing stored in the filter will collide an average of k/m times with another thing stored in the same filter"*. This is true of the Akiva filter, but the collision chance for a Bloom filter is actually a little lower than than k/m, because in a Bloom filter, when you hash a thing *k* times with your *k* hash functions, on average you get (slightly) less than *k* **distinct** array indexes.